# How can I draw only the region on the waveform using wavesurfer?

Tags: wavesurfer.js

I have created the region below and now I want only that region to be drawn on the waveform when the audio file is loaded.

```
plugins: [
WaveSurfer.regions.create({
    regions: [
        {
            id: "your id",   
            start: 60,
            end: 80,
            loop: false,
            color: '#cccccc'
        }
    ]
})
```

]

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should initialize creation, with an empty object and no params:

```
plugins: [ Regions.create({}) ]
```

after that add region using addRegion method:

```
WaveSurfer.addRegion({ 
      id: "your id",   
      start: 60,
      end: 80,
      loop: false,
      color: '#cccccc'
})
```